# this name '_form1' doesn't exist in current context

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
namespace WindowsApplication

public partial class Form1: Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Form1 = this;
    }    
}
```

error: **The name '_Form1' doesn't exist in current context**

Comment: Where is declaration `_Form1`? What is `_Form1`?

Comment: in visual studio right click on _Form1 and choose "Go to definition". If it exists than you have found it, if not than the code is just wrong.

Comment: Why do you want to store `this` in `_Form1`?! Just use `this` when you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You forgot to declare _Form1:

```
Form1 _Form1;
_Form1 = this;
```

Comment: Wow, voting down a correct answer.  I guess Reza's comment of why do you need _Form1 defined anyway is more appropriate in this scenario.  You are only storing a reference to itself here - not copying the form.

Comment: @ArulSivaram Be adviced though, that you do not get an actual copy by doing this, since you do not get a copy by value but by reference. If you just want to name `this` you are fine that way. ^^